# Using xargs with Special characters

Tags: linux, bash, xargs

I have the following problem.
Got a file which includes certain paths/files of a FS.
These for some reason do include the whole range of special characters, like space, single/double quotes, even sometimes the Copyright ASCII.

I need to run each line of the file and pass it to another command.

What I tried so far is:

```
<input_file xargs -I % command %
```

Which was working until I got this message from xargs

```
xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option
```

But usinf this option did not work at all for me

```
xargs: argument line too long
```

Does anybody have a solution which does work ok with special characters.
Doesn't have to be with xargs, but I need to pass the line as it is to the command.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Technically a POSIX-compliant file name may include any byte except '\0' and '/'. So if you need to work with a set of files which names may contain "weird symbols" you should choose the only available separator '\0'. Don't know if it's possible to convert your file list into '\0'-separated list. What symbol to separate filenames is in use right now?

Comment: Ha, thanks for the hint. I never thought about changing the delimiter. But I did now, and it seems to work: <input_file xargs -d '\n\' command

Comment: Picking nits, but there is no such thing as "Copyright ASCII".

Answer (score 9):

You should separate the filenames with the `\0` NULL character for processing.

This can be done with

```
find . <args> -print0 | xargs -0
```

or if you must process the file with filenames, change the '\n` to '\0', e.g.

```
tr '\n' '\0' < filename | xargs -0 -n1 -I% echo "==%=="
```

the `-n 1` says,

> -n max-args
>    Use at most max-args arguments per command line.

and you should to use `"%"` quotes to enclosing `%`

Comment: the `tr` bit doesn't work as `tr` doesn't take a file as argument. You have to pipe `cat filename` to it

Comment: Thanks Nemo, I ended up just changing the delimiter with xargs: <input_file xargs -d '\n\' command

Answer (score 0):

The `xargs -0 -n1 -I% echo "==%=="` solution didn't work for me on my Mac OS X, so I found another one.

```sh
<input_with_single_quotes cat | sed "s/'/\\\'/" | xargs -I {} echo {}
```

This replaces the `'` character with `\'` that works well as an input to the commands in `xargs`.